# Manually creating an object that looks like a heatmap color key

Tags: r, layout, graphics, key

I'm working on trying to create a key for a heatmap, but as far as I know, I cannot use the existing tools for adding a legend since I've generated the colors myself (I manually turn a scaled variable into rgb values for a short rainbow ( [255,0,0] to [0,0,255] ).

Basically, all I want to do is use the rightmost 10th of the screen to create a rectangle with these 10 colors: "#0000FF", "#0072FF", "#00E3FF", "#00FFAA", "#00FF38", "#39FF00", "#AAFF00", "#FFE200", "#FF7100", "#FF0000"

with three numerical labels - at 0, max/2, and max

In essence, I want to manually produce an object that looks like a rudimentary heatmap color key.

As far as I know, split.screen can only split the screen in half, which isn't what I'm looking for. I want the graphic I already know how to produce to take up the leftmost 90% of the screen, and I want this colored rectangle to take up the other 10%.

Thanks.

EDIT: I greatly appreciate the advice about the best way to the the plot - that said, I still would like to know the best way to do the task originally asked - creating the legend by hand; I already am able to produce the exact heatmap graphic that I'm looking for - the false coloring wasn't the only problem with ggplot that I was having - it was just the final factor convincing me to switch. I need a non ggplot solution.

EDIT #2: This is close to the solution I am looking for, except this only goes up to 10 instead of accepting a maximum value as a parameter (I will be running this code on multiple data-sets, all with different maximum values - I want the legend to reflect this). Additionally, if I change the size of the graph, the key falls apart into disconnected squares.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the layouts function ([link](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html)). I think you want something like this:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(9,1))
## plot heatmap
## plot legend
```

I would also recommend the ggplot2 package and the geom_tile function which will take care of all of this for you.

Assuming your data is in a data frame with the x and y coordinates and heatmap value (e.g. `gdat <- data.frame(x_coord=c(1,2,...), y_coord=c(1,1,...), val=c(6,2,...))`) Then you should be able to produce your desired heat map plot with the following ggplot command:

```
ggplot(gdat) + geom_tile(aes(x=x_coord, y=y_coord, fill=val)) + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low="#0000FF", high="#FF0000")
```

To get your data into the following format you may want to look into the very useful reshape2 package.

Given a script no ggplot restriction on this answer here is how one could produce the plot with just base R.

```
colors <- c("#0000FF", "#0072FF", "#00E3FF", "#00FFAA", "#00FF38",
            "#39FF00", "#AAFF00", "#FFE200", "#FF7100", "#FF0000")
layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(9,1))
plot(rnorm(20), rnorm(20), col=sample(colors, 20, replace=TRUE))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(x=rep(1,10), y=1:10, col=colors, pch=15, cex=7.1)
```

You may have to adjust the cex for your device.

Comment: I'll try using layout and see how that works. I initially was trying to use ggplot2, but that was massively distorting the colors I was using, as well as being insufficiently flexible about dot sizes. Eventually, I abandoned the package. 

I'm still looking for the best way to make the actual multi-colored rectangle that would serve as the legend and apply numerical labels in the correct place.

Comment: Can you post your attempted ggplot code? I have never seen it distort colors before and it would make the legend creation trivial. Were you using the `scale_color_manual` function to set the colors? The syntax for ggplot can take a little bit to learn, but it is indeed incredibly flexible and powerful once you learn it.

Comment: I'll see if I still have the ggplot code I was using. I think I was using col = < a vector with hex values in it>

Comment: Indeed that was likely your problem. ggplot treats the `col` values as factors and assigning them completely different colors. I'll add a quick ggplot script to produce a heatmap with legend in ggplot.

Comment: I should clarify that this is a essentially a 3 variable scatterplot, not the type of heatmap that most online ggplot tutorials are for, and  color wasn't the only problem with how the ggplot graph looked.

Comment: In your second edit you say that you would like to accept any number of parameters, but you only supply 10 colors. What would you expect for larger numbers of colors?

Comment: The code I'm using to make the heatmap generates rgb parameters, so it can make as many colors as are necessary - however, I only want the legend to include 10 evenly spaced colors. Basically, I just meant that the legend needs to have 0 at red, and a supplied parameter at blue.